# Homeomorphism $(\mathbb{CP}^1)^m/S_m \overset{\sim}{\to} \mathbb{CP}^m$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, projective-space

For each $m \ge 1$, how do I construct a homeomorphism $(\mathbb{CP}^1)^m/S_m \overset{\sim}{\to} \mathbb{CP}^m$?

**My thoughts so far:** I probably want to identify $\mathbb{C}^{m+1}$ with the vector space $\mathbb{C}^m[z, w]$ of degree $m$ homogeneous polynomials in two variables and use that a polynomial in one variable is determined by its roots up to a nonzero constant factor somehow... but from here, I'm kinda of stuck. Could someone help?

**EDIT: Progress so far.** After reading Eric Wofsey's response, I have the following. Since a projective variety is determined by its homogeneous coordinate ring, it suffices to determine the homogeneous coordinate ring of $(\mathbb{CP}^1)^m/S_m$.

For $(\mathbb{CP}^1)^m$, the coordinate ring is the graded ring $\mathcal{S}$ whose $d$th degree part is the $m$-fold tensor product (over $\mathbb{C}$) of $\mathbb{C}[s, t]_{d}$. That is, $S_d$ consists of polynomials in $s^1, t^1, s^2, t^2, \dots, s^m, t^m$ of multidegree ($d, d, \dots, d$). And $S_m$ acts in the obvious way, i.e. if $\sigma(i) = j$, then $\sigma$ sends $s^i$ to $s^j$ and $t^i$ to $t^j$. The homogeneous coordinate ring of $(\mathbb{CP}^1)^m/S_m$ is just the ring of invariants of the $S_m$ action on $\mathcal{S}$. But I still have two questions.

- Which polynomials are invariant under this action?
- I still don't see how to conclude that Eric Wofsey's map is a homeomorphism. How do I see that Eric Wofsey's map is a homeomorphism?

Comment: Bullet point 2: You show that it's continuous, and then write down a continuous inverse. This is sort of a tautological statement but really, that's what you do. (Alternatively, since your domain is compact and codomain Hausdorff, you just show it's a continuous bijection.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're on the right track; the idea is to take the fact that a polynomial in one variable is determined by its roots and homogenize all the polynomials.  You can define a map $f:(\mathbb{CP}^1)^m/S_m\to\mathbb{CP}^m$ by identifying an element $[a,b]\in\mathbb{CP}^1$ with a homogeneous linear polynomial $az+bw$ (defined up to scalar multiples) and then multiplying $m$ such polynomials to get a homogeneous degree $m$ polynomial $c_0z^m+c_1z^{m-1}w+\dots+c_mw^m$ (up to scalar multiples), which can then be identified with $[c_0,\dots,c_m]\in\mathbb{CP}^m$.  This is just a homogeneous analogue of the bijection $\mathbb{C}^m/S_m\to \mathbb{C}^m$ which takes $m$ numbers and gives you the coefficients of the monic polynomial which has those numbers as roots.  Can you prove that this map is a homeomorphism?

Comment: I've updated my progress to my original post.